# How to config nginx to use language folder as a parameter?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Using NGinx, i'd like to have URLs like

> mydomain.com/LANG/foo?a=b

to be used as

> mydomain.com/foo?lang=LANG&a=b

Where "LANG" can be only "fr" or "en" or "de".

For example

> mydomain.com/en/dog?id=123&code=abcd

to be used as

> mydomain.com/dog?lang=en&id=123&code=abcd

I do not want the URL to be changed in my browser.

I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: The answer probably depends on how the rewritten URI is eventually processed, but the basic rewrite statement is: `rewrite ^/(fr|en|de)(/.*)$ $2?lang=$1;`

Comment: Thx it works. I just don't understand how it deals with the parameters id and code in the example, because it will be transformed to mydomain.com/dog?id=123&code=abcd?lang=en with the character "?" twice...

Comment: Or maybe NGinx is clever enougth (more than me) to understand that the second "?" has to be transformed into a "&"...

Comment: `rewrite` will append the original arguments unless the replacement string ends with a `?`. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.